# cake 1.3 - cache does not load models

Tags: cakephp, caching, model, cakephp-1.3

in my users_controller i have:

```
var $uses = array('User', ...);
function dosomething() {
  $this->User->findById($someId);
  ...
}
```

it works fine for about an hour, after that, i have error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function findById() on a non-object
```

when i make `dump($this)` it shows me that `$this->User` is only an empty string.

after i delete all files from TMP.'cache' it works fine for another hour.
if i'll disable cache it works fine all the time

i've tried

`Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));`

and

`Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'APC'));`

it works the same.

unfortunately i need cache, so please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think cache default duration is 1 hour. If the first time it is correctly created and 1 hour later it can't be regenerated, I guess your problem may be related to permissions. I mean, look like you have permissions to create cache files, but you can't delete it later.

Comment: i don't think thats the problem. It's not exactly 1h every time. During the day it could stop working after 50m, and it could work fine whole night. Mostly it's 1h. It looks more like problem with reading - it thinks that model is in cache, but it's not there.

Comment: p.s. it's not only with User. Sometimes different model is broken.